# ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file - Mysql server not starting

Tags: mysql, macos, pid

When I try to start mysql

```
Password:
 ERROR! MySQL server PID file could not be found!
Starting MySQL
.Logging to '/usr/local/mysql/data/F.f.com.err'.
ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/usr/local/mysql/data/F.f.com.pid).
```

There is no mysql process running

```
F:data app$ ps aux | grep mysql
app      1665   0.0  0.0  4269080    816 s002  S+   11:00PM   0:00.00 grep mysql
```

When I try to access the file

```
FWS:~ app $ ls /usr/local/mysql/data/F.f.com.err
ls: /usr/local/mysql/data/F.f.com.err: No such file or directory
FWS:~ app$
```

Comment: Is this the first time you try to start MySQL or has it worked in the past

Comment: It has worked in the past. Suddenly am experiencing this issue now

Answer (score 0):

sudo chmod -R 777 /usr/local/mysql/

After giving complete permission it worked. No idea on how the permissions were overwritten